# The email has already been taken. Even i try to add new email address

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, form-submit

I am facing very uncertain issues with Laravel 5.8. While creating user using User::create();

If I set the validation for a unique email so it will return me error i.e {"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"email":["The email has already been taken."]}} else it's insetting 4 records in the database for the same email address.

Here is my controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Auth;
use DB;
use App\User;
use App\Logs;
use App\Role_user;
use App\Model\Admin\Modules_permission;
class UsersController extends Controller
{
  protected $slugData;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('admin');
    $this->slugData = DB::table('modules as m')
                      ->Join('sub_modules as sm','sm.module_id','m.id')
                      ->select('sm.name as superSlug', 'sm.slug as subSlug')
                      ->where('m.id', '=', '2')
                      ->where('sm.id', '=', '5')
                      ->get()
                      ->toArray();
  }

  public function adminUsersCreate(Request $request){
    $request->validate([
                'name'         => 'required',
                'branch'       => 'required',
                'role'         => 'required',
                'status'       => 'required',
                'super_module' => 'required',
                'password'     => 'required|min:5',
                //'email'        => 'required|email'
                'email'        => 'required|email|unique:users'
            ], [
                'branch.required'       => 'Please select branch.',
                'role.required'         => 'Please select role.',
                'status.required'       => 'Status is required',
                'super_module.required' => 'Please select super module.',
                'name.required'         => 'Name is required',
                'password.required'     => 'Password is required'
            ]);
      try {
          if(!empty($request->institute)){
            $userData['institute_id'] = $request->institute;
            if(!empty($request->user_type)){
              $userData['institute_user_type_id'] = $request->user_type;
            }
          }
          $userData['type']          = 'user';
          $userData['name']          = $request->name;
          $userData['email']         = $request->email;
          $userData['password']      = bcrypt($request->password);
          $userData['password_view'] = $request->password;
          $userData['branch_id']     = $request->branch;
          $userData['status']        = $request->status;
          $userData['created_by']    = Auth::user()->id;
          // echo "<pre>";print_r($userData);echo "</pre>";die;
          $user                      = User::create($userData);
          if(@$user->id >0){
              $message['type']    = 'POST';
              $message['success'] = 'User create successfully+++';            
            $roleData['user_id'] = $user->id;
            $roleData['role_id'] = $request->role;
            $role                = Role_user::create($roleData);
            if($role->id != 0 && !empty($role)){
              if($request->super_module != 'not_that_time' && !empty($request->permission)){
                $permUser    = $user->id;
                $permissions = $request->permission;
                foreach ($permissions as $key => $subModule) {
                  $permData['user_id']    = $permUser;
                  $permData['created_by'] = Auth::user()->id;
                  $permData['module_id']  = $key;
                  foreach ($subModule as $key => $cruds){
                    $permData['submodule_id'] = $key;
                    $permID                   = Modules_permission::create($permData);
                    $permUpdateID             = Modules_permission::whereId($permID->id)->update($cruds);
                    if($permUpdateID == 0 || empty($permID) || $permID->id == 0){
                      $routeName                = Route::getCurrentRoute();
                      $message['type']          = 'POST';
                      $message['user_id']       = Auth::user()->id;
                      $message['opretion']      = 'Login User Create';
                      $message['error_message'] = 'Permission update failed afetr create user';
                      $message['url']           = $routeName->action['controller'];
                      Logs::create($message);
                    }elseif($permUpdateID == 1){
                      $message['type']    = 'POST';
                      $message['success'] = 'User create successfully';
                    }
                  }
                }
              }else{
                $message['type']    = 'POST';
                $message['success'] = 'User create successfully without permissions';
              }
            }else{
              $routeName                = Route::getCurrentRoute();
              $message['type']          = 'POST';
              $message['user_id']       = Auth::user()->id;
              $message['opretion']      = 'Login User Create';
              $message['error_message'] = 'Role ID not get afetr create user';
              $message['url']           = $routeName->action['controller'];
              Logs::create($message);
            } 
          }else{
            $routeName                = Route::getCurrentRoute();
            $message['type']          = 'POST';
            $message['user_id']       = Auth::user()->id;
            $message['opretion']      = 'Login User Create';
            $message['error_message'] = 'User create failed';
            $message['url']           = $routeName->action['controller'];
            Logs::create($message);
          }
          return Response()->json($message);
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        $routeName                = Route::getCurrentRoute();
        $message['type']          = 'POST';
        $message['user_id']       = Auth::user()->id;
        $message['opretion']      = 'Login User Create';
        $message['error_message'] = $ex->getMessage();
        $message['url']           = $routeName->action['controller'];
        Logs::create($message);
        return Response()->json($message);
    }

  }
}
```

User Model and relation:-

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'type', 'name', 'gender', 'institute_id', 'institute_user_type_id','password_view', 'land_line', 'permanent_address', 'mobile', 'dob', 'corresp_address', 'pin_code', 'photo', 'email', 'password','branch_id','status','created_by'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function roles()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }

    public function rolesByID()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');
    }
}
```

**JS used to submit the form:-**

```
$(function() {
  $('.add-subadmin-form').validate({
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'error',
    rules: {
        name: "required",
        email: {
          required: true,
          email: true,
          // remote: checkEmail()
        },
        password: {
          required: true,
                    pwcheck: true,
          minlength: 5
        },
      },
      // Specify validation error messages
      messages: {
        name: "Please enter your name.",
        password: {
          required: "Please provide a password.",
                    pwcheck: "minimum 1 capital letters and lowercase letters with number and special characters",
          minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long."
        },
        email: "Please enter a valid email address.",
        branch:{
          required: "Please select branch.",
        },
        super_module:{
          required: "Please select super module.",
        },
        sub_moduless:{
          required: "Please select sub module.",
        },
        role:{
          required: "Please select role.",
        },

      },
      submitHandler: function(form) {
        if(returnData == 0){
          $('span.emailExist').text('This email is already exist');
          $("span.emailExist").css("display", "block");
          return false;
        }else {
          $('span.emailExist').remove();
          var postedData  = $('.add-subadmin-form').serialize();
          $.ajax({
            url: SITE_URL+'/admin/admin-users-Create',
            method:"POST",
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('input[name="_token"]').val()
            },
            data: $('.add-subadmin-form').serialize(),
            success:function(response){
               console.log(response);
              if(response.success){
                notify({
                    type: "success", //alert | success | error | warning | info
                    title: "Success! "+response.success,
                    showHideTransition: 'fade',
                            position: {
                        x: "right", //right | left | center
                        y: "top" //top | bottom | center
                    },
                    icon: '<img src="'+Asses_url+'/public/assets/images/paper_plane.png" />',
                    // message: response.success
                });
                window.setTimeout(function(){
                  window.location.href = SITE_URL+"/admin/admin-users-list";
                }, 2000);
              }else if(response.error_message){
                ntotify({
                    type: "error", //alert | success | error | warning | info
                    title: "Error",
                            position: {
                        x: "right", //right | left | center
                        y: "top" //top | bottom | center
                    },
                    icon: '<img src="'+Asses_url+'/public/assets/images/paper_plane.png" />',
                    message: response.error_message
                });
              }
            }
          });
          // form.submit();
        }

      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Are you saying if you apply validation to ensure the email address is unique, you then get a validation error saying the email address is already in use? Then if you remove the validation you get multiple (4) records in the database with the same email? Are you truncating the users table each time before running the request and getting 4 entries every time?

Comment: Hi Jon, 
No, I am not truncating the table. My question is that if I even add a new entry with a new email it inserts the entry in the database and then returns the error message of The email has already been taken.

Comment: Okay that's interesting. It sounds like your DB insert is running before you validation. I would be helpful to see more of your code in the context of your controller so we can where the code you've given sits. I prefer to use Form Requests for validation in Laravel, it creates a good separation between your controller logic and validation logic and allows Laravel to handle the order of execution.

Comment: John code is written by someone else and he submitting the form using js form submit and serializing the data. When I check in console request is submitting once only. if I use dd() after creating it insert only a single entry else it enters multiple.

Comment: I don't think I can offer much help without being able to follow the entire execution path. But the fact that if you dd() after the create you get only a single entry suggests the following code is triggering something that repeats the insert somewhere. Possibly something in the JS that awaits the response? You should consider setting a unique constraint on the email column in the DB. Then you might be able to identify where the subsequent inserts happen as they will throw errors that you can trace.

Comment: Jon I updated the question and add the controller and model with js code which used to submit the form hope it will be more clear to you now.